# Download big files from android, with a recovery on error

Tags: android, http, download

I developed an app that have to download very large files, 100 MB average.
Everything works, but some times for normal reason like Mobile connection that go down to 0 for some seconds or wireless standby, the download that run in a service (like the update of the market) can be broken or interrupted.
There is a way for recovery on error, maybe with an http range?
If someone already had the problem will be nice to have an example of working code. :-)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server, use "split" on the file to split it into many smaller files, and generate a check file of md5sums with md5sum.

On the android, you'll need to download all the pieces, check the md5sum, go back and get any that didn't download correctly and then cat them together.

I've never done this on the android but have used it many a time with flaky telephone modem connections in the bad old days.

Comment: This would work, but isn't it a little overkill? I'm no Android developer but he could just as easily split the file in virtual chunks. Request the chunks from server (Using HTTP range), use a bitfield for chunk status, and request undelivered chunks back again. No need for checksums, TCP/IP will make sure that the data is correct. Commenting because I have no answer regarding to the implementation on Android.

Comment: @Ekin Depends on whether it is easier to make an HTTP range request than it is to break the file up on the server.  The only reason for checksumming is to deal with interrupted downloads without knowing the file size. Dinsosaur-ish, I know.

Comment: If I split the file on the server than, I don't need any particular call, I just give to my client the url of the different pieces with partial checksum just for tell to the customer which pieces are invalid or broken and than re-download it. My idea was to use http range without split the files, in this case you can also solve the problem if you don't have a control on the server, than you can't split the file. My question was more like which is the best practice to catch particular download error and ask to the user to restore it with http range method?

Comment: @Mauro Well assuming you are running in java on the android, wouldn't it be either catching an exception thrown by the download handler or checking a return code...